# リモート側にもパスワード等を記載するファイルをOpenにしても差し支えない内容で配備したい

Tags: git, vscode, gitlab

秘密にしておきたい情報がconnect.propertiesに書かれている想定では、一般的には以下のような構成になっていると認識しています。

- リモート側
  /test
  ├.gitignore
  └sample01.ps1
- ローカル側
  /test
  ├.gitignore
  ├sample01.ps1
  └connect.properties

これをリモート側にも以下のような感じでOpenしても差し支えない内容でconnect.propertiesを配備しておきたいと考えているのですが何か良い方法ないでしょうか。（あまり関係ないかもしれませんが当方VScodeで使ってます）

- リモート側に配備しておきたいconnect.properties
  HOSTNAME = xxxxxxx
  DB       = xxxxxxx
  USER     = xxxxxxx
  PASS     = xxxxxxx

個人的には最初にクローンして、ファイルを一から作るより内容書き換えだけでつかえるので便利かとおもうのですが、、、
gitはあまり詳しくないのでもしかするとかなり恥ずかしい質問になっているかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします